# Small div floating inside of a larger div

Tags: html, css

I have a google map that takes up 100% of the width and height of the screen.  Well, the height is set to 1000px because I can't get it to go to 100%, but that's another question.  Anyway, I want to have the #map div to take up the full screen and display a rectangular box to the right of the screen - this is a div that would have the class set to 'search_box'.

I am having two problems with the html and css in my app:

1. The rectangular box does show up on the right of the page as I want it, but it shows up UNDER the google map, so you can't see it!  I can only confirm this because if I refresh the page, it does show up for a split second before the google map covers it. :(
2. I want the box to be about 50px lower than the menu above it, but padding-top doesn't seem to do anything.  I'm not sure if this is because it's floating.  Any ideas?

Also, should the 'search_box' div be inside of the 'map' div?

**In my HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="search_box"></div>
```

**In my CSS**

```
.search_box {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: add fiddle and update your code

Comment: @RJeyashri : Here is the fiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/3bV3M/ ,Now let me know thw answer please.

Comment: To get the google map to be 100% height, you have to set all ancestors' height to 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/3bV3M/1/

Comment: Also, don't use floats—they're evil.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri_shri/R6eZF/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the search box to float next to the map you'll need to float #map as well. If you want the search box inside of the map, you should wrap them both in a containing div and position the search box absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

To position the search box on the right side of the map, wrap both the `div`s inside another `div`.

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="search_box"></div>
</div>
```

Now use `absolute position` for the search div to position it on the right side of the map.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/8MpNn/)**

CSS

```
.map-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.search_box {
  background-color: blue;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you would want/care to position an element beneath another that completely covers it, but: http://jsfiddle.net/3bV3M/5/

Re-order your DOM:

```
div.search-box
div#map
```

`#map` should have position:absolute to take it out of the normal document flow but allow its position to still be controlled. I left .search-box on top of #map so you can see it positioned; to move it behind, remove the `z-index: 1;`. Note that I enabled [css normalisation](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) on the fiddle.

```
html, body {
    display:      block;
    height:       100%;
    position:     relative;
    width:        100%;
}
.search_box {
    background:   red;
    height:       1.2rem;
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    position:     relative;
    top:          50px;
    /* use `top` instead of `margin-top`, it doesnt contribute to the box */
    width:        5rem;
    z-index:      1; /* remove me */
}
#map {
    background:   black;
    height:       100%;
    position:     absolute;
    top:          0;
    width:        100%;
}
```